# How to make High Level Design Document ETL

Tags: azure, etl

I will be very much Thankful if someone can share their experience while designing ETL.

I am trying to prepare High Level Design Document. This is first time i am architecture the ETL Solution.

May some one please help me what are the things we must take care while designing.

**The flat file comes from vendor every week, we need to load and generate report.**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, I recommend an **ELT for Azure SQL Data Warehouse** based on an ETL approach.

> The flat file comes from vendor every week, we need to load and generate report.

This ELT process is performed on a regular basis, for example hourly, daily or weekly, to get newly generated data into the data warehouse.

You could refer to these basic steps:

1. Extract the source data into text files.
2. Land the data into Azure Blob storage or Azure Data Lake Store.
3. Prepare the data for loading.
4. Load the data into SQL Data Warehouse staging tables by using **PolyBase**.
5. Transform the data.
6. Insert the data into production tables.

PolyBase is a technology that accesses data outside of the database via the T-SQL language. It is the best way to load data into SQL Data Warehouse.

For more details , please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/design-elt-data-loading).